# Flutter/Dart security scans

Tags: security, flutter, dart

I'm looking for software/method to perform a security scan (looking for security vulnerabilities) on my apps being developed in Flutter. I'm having troubles find one that supports Dart. Has anyone been doing security scans and have any recommendations for what to use? Thanks.

Comment: hope this article help it may give you some info about what you want                                       https://blog.tst.sh/reverse-engineering-flutter-apps-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

There's no great security scanning support at the moment although there are some discussions. The first step would be for Google to start to track Dart vulnerabilities in their existing Open Source Vulnerability (OSV) database, you could watch or get involved here: https://github.com/google/osv/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this might be a necropost but for anyone else who comes across this, you could look into Black Duck (https://www.blackducksoftware.com/) for licensing risks and Checkmarx CxSAST (https://checkmarx.com/) for security issues. Both support Dart/Flutter code (we've integrated into our ADO pipelines).

These would be for organisations rather than individuals though.

For private projects, I guess you could look into [this integration into SonarQube](https://github.com/insideapp-oss/sonar-flutter)?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30344253)

Comment: There's no new question in my post - it was a suggestion.

Comment: Hi jilan, I've check CheckMarx document and can not find flutter support. They only support native android and iOS. Could you give me some information about Flutter Support with CheckMarx please? Many thanks

Comment: Hi Luan Si Ho, I don't have that much information because it was set up by my organisation, but looking into the scan logs, the tool scans the native Android portion of the project. Presumably a separate project would need to be set up to scan the IOS part. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the open source framework called **mobsf**. It's great at scanning a mobile app. I have been using it ever since and I could start patching up my security vulnerability right away.

link : https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF

Answer (score 1):

`Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF` Great Tools For Doing Mobile Applications  Security Test